# Google Sheets: Move a cell value to next empty position in Range on sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to select multiple choice options from a drop down box.

I have this sample spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BKWZWHRvdLIc8k3MzT4ARENe2s-qD-AW5vegOMs_jqw/edit?usp=sharing

The Clear and Submit buttons should not be a problem.

I am having issues that when I click on "Add another ATA" button, I would like an app script to move the value in D7 to the next available blank cell in the range J2:J13 and then remove the value in D7 to await a new value, then click "Add another ATA" and move the new value to the next available blank cell in the range J2:J13 etc...

I have succeeded in moving the value from D7 to J2 for example.

I cant figure out how to establish via app script how to calculate what cells are blank or not so I know where to insert the code.

I have tried putting the Range J2:13 in an array and cycling through it but I wasn't successful identifying the next available blank cell range.

Comment: You are not showing any code in your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you wish to do if there are no blank cells in J2:J13

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function. Paste it in your script project and call it like this:

```js
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getRange('D7').getValue();
  const result = appendRows_(sheet, data, 10);
```

...where `10` means column `J`.